# Jupyter lab autosave interval

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

How can I configure the autosave interval for JupyterLab?

Is there any advances since this issue -
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5619

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you linked is now closed as the [linked PR](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/5645) implemented a setting allowing to change the interval using `autosaveInterval` in Settings / Settings Editor / Document Manager.

[image]